# Using Moment-range in angular 2 without Typings

Tags: angular, webpack, momentjs, angular-cli

I'm trying to use moment-range library with Angular 2 but typings seems to be outdated, is there a possibility to use the library directly in TypeScript ?

I tried to include the .js file in angular-cli.json script array but I get an error :
`Property 'range' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'`

I'm using Angular CLI version 1.0.0-rc.1 with Webpack, and Moment range 3.0.3.

Thx in advance.

Comment: it looks like an open issue in [github](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range/issues/120). Removed my answer.. @types is old as well

Comment: I'm also trying to make it work using twix.js but it seems that typings are also outdated !

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/twix

Comment: This is a really common problem in TypeScript ):

Comment: With twix, `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_moment__.twix is not a function` :(